# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Tags: python, django

I didn't seem to find this specific error.

I am sending a POST to a function in django and when I try to extract the data I come across this message on the request.getlist line:

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'getlist'
```

The function is:

```
def function(request, a_id, b_id):
    return_val = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.getlist("message")

        #Stuff

    return render_to_response("return.html", {'res':return_val}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: `request.POST.getlist("message")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
message = request.POST.getlist("message")
```

In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of `django.http.QueryDict`. `getlist` is method of [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) and not `HttpRequest`.